# Using pandas function how to do following analysis for the same code which is done for individual

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Data:

```
    Sr.No   Village    Taluka  District      LSWI   TEMP  FAPAR  PAR
0       1  Belundgi  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.299471  19.25     12  2.5
1       2  Belundgi  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.268066  18.26     14  3.2
2       3  Belundgi  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.252687  17.25     14  3.0
3       4  Belundgi  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.271744  16.28     15  2.0
4       5  Belundgi  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.258911  19.26     17  3.0
5       6  Belundgi  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.295071  10.00     15  5.0
6       7  Belundgi  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.297177  11.00     12  4.0
7       8  Gobbur B  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.265798  15.00     14  3.0
8       9  Gobbur B  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.206717  14.25     15  1.0
9      10  Gobbur B  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.134919  21.25     14  2.0
10     11  Gobbur B  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.283957  24.52     15  6.0
11     12  Gobbur B  Afsalpur  Gulbarga  0.241955  21.25     10  3.0
```

I have done some work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\lenovo2\Desktop\data.xlsx')
LSWI=df['LSWI']
LSWI_Max=LSWI.loc[df['LSWI'].idxmax()]
W=np.array(1-df['LSWI'])/np.array(1+LSWI_Max)
T1=np.array(df['TEMP']-5)*np.array(df['TEMP']-35)
T2=T1-np.array(df['TEMP']-25)*np.array(df['TEMP']-25)
T=T1/T2
Delta=df['PAR']*df['FAPAR']*3
```

Above code,I have to apply as a village wise.
So I am trying to use function to calculate,but function formula not working properly, here is my code which is giving me error

```
def f(x):
    x['LSWI'] =x.groupby(["Taluka","Village"])['LSWI'].transform('sum')
    x['LSWI_Max']=x['LSWI'].loc[df['LSWI'].idxmax()]
    x['W']=1-x['LSWI'])/1+x['LSWI_Max']
    x['T1']=x['TEMP']-5)*x['TEMP']-35)
    x['T2']=x['T1']-df['TEMP']-25)*df['TEMP']-25)
    x['T']=x['T1']/x['T2']
    x['Delta']=df['PAR']*df['FAPAR']*3
    return x

df1=df.groupby(["Taluka","Village"]).apply(f)
```

What is wrong in function code,I got the error, any ideas how to do this in function formula?

Comment: It seems not all `df` are replaced to `x`

Comment: @jezrael, I tried but still error. also, I just try for first two lines in function command, and apply function still get error

Comment: @jezrael, x['LSWI'] and x['LSWI_Max'] only 2 lines apply bot got error

Comment: Can you add expected output? Because I tested sample data with replaced all `df` to `x` and no error. also what is error?

Comment: @jezrael , 
  File "C:\Users\lenovo2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3291, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: 'Taluka'

Comment: There are column name `Taluka` ? `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: Is it because you use groupby 2 times? Once in the function call and once in the definition?

Comment: @jezrael,print (df.columns.tolist())
['Sr.No', 'Village', 'Taluka', 'District', 'LSWI', 'TEMP', 'FAPAR', 'PAR']

Comment: @jezrael, am I mistake to calculate maximum value for LSWI to find for village wise in function?